# Determining Highest and Lowest Numbers in an Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to write java code to find the two highest and the smallest number in an array given the below conditions:

-Every element is a real number

-Every element is random

Any ideas on the best approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to examine every number, so your best algorithm is linear in the length of the array.

The standard approach is to just scan the array, keeping track of the two smallest and largest numbers that you've seen so far.

So, given that `firstMin`, `secondMin`, `firstMax`, `secondMax` are respectively the smallest, second smallest, largest and second largest values that you've seen so far, on the next iteration of the loop:

```
if (value > firstMax) {
    secondMax = firstMax;
    firstMax = value;
} 
else if (value > secondMax) {
    secondMax = value;
}

if (value < firstMin) {
    secondMin = firstMin; 
    firstMin = value;
}
else if (value < secondMin) {
    secondMin = value;
}
```

At the end of this block, we maintain the invariant that `firstMin`, `secondMin`, `firstMax`, `secondMax` are respectively the smallest, second smallest, largest and second largest values that you've seen so far. This proves correctness.

This algorithm is linear in the length of the array and examines each value exactly once and makes the minimum number of comparisons. It is also `O(1)` in space, and is optimal in that it uses only four extra memory locations for the top and bottom two values.

Comment: I think it's important to note that this algorithm is space and time optimal.

Comment: This is the proper approach. You might want to include in your answer the initialization of all the max|min variables to array[0].

Comment: Nice answer, perfectly exact & correct. No idea who's the clown who is down-voting. When is the questioner going to accept one of the answers?

Comment: You're going to need to initialize the max's to some minimal value and the mins to some maximal value to account for all cases as well.

Comment: @ardentsonata: No, because I'm *only* showing the update step inside the loop. I am *not* showing the full code.

Comment: @Jason - I used Integer.MIN_VALUE; for the two high varibales and Integer.MAX_VALUE; for the two low variables.  I can't use null or I get a NPE and if I use 0 then I may not get the low/high values.  Is there a better way to initialize the Integer variables?

Answer (score 5):

Have a variable to keep track of the min, second_min, max, and second_max values that you have seen so far.

You can go through the elements of the array one by one, and update your min/max variables accordingly.  Here are some cases to consider:

- If current element is smaller than your min, save your min to second_min and update your min.
- If current element is larger than your max, save your max to second_max and update your max
- If current element is smaller then second_min, but larger than min, update second_min only
- If current element is larger then second_max, but smaller than max, update second_max only

Comment: This answer is correct & fine. I gave it a +1. Thanks for your effort on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Is super-optimized performance necessary?  If not,

```
Arrays.sort( array );
```

Look at the first and last two elements.

Comment: would this be noticeably slower than the for loop approach for huge arrays?

Comment: @c12 for some values of 'huge' and some values of 'noticeably'.  Sorting an array of 100k randomly-generated ints takes ~14 ms on my machine; sorting 1m takes about 100ms.  Those values may be shockingly slow or perfectly fine to you, depending on what you're doing with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is use the array as a heap or a special data structure if you can. Keeping the structure balance and sorted will be most efficient for you. This implies keeping some elements empty at some indixes in your array since the index of the array will be information about your ADT. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: Heap is overkill; useful if you need top and bottom `k` for general `k`, or top and bottom `k` for large `k`, but my goodness not for top and bottom two.